# Pytube is always failing with urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Is there a fix for this issue?

Tags: python, pytube

I have been using pytube for years and within the last few days have been getting HTTP 404 errors. I updated my code to retry several times after a delay and that worked for a while.  However, now I am always getting the error no matter how many times I retry. The suggested fix from a few days ago was to upgrade to pytube using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ssuwani/pytube
```

I have done this but still get the same 404 error. Here is an example run:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\bayki>python
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pytube import YouTube
>>> YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn8ZuOCn6r0').streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 308, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 213, in fmt_streams
    if "adaptive_fmts" in self.player_config_args:
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 187, in player_config_args
    self._player_config_args = self.vid_info
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 278, in vid_info
    return dict(parse_qsl(self.vid_info_raw))
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 108, in vid_info_raw
    self._vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 52, in get
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bayki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>>>
```

Comment: Hey @PyNZ Internet issue?? check it is connected or not!

Comment: I would be interested to know if those two lines of code work for anyone else? Maybe YouTube is behaving differently in different locations.

Comment: I have also installed the latest version of pytube3 on Google colab and the above code also fails with HTTP Error 404

Comment: However the latest version of pytube on Google colab appears to work.

Comment: Ok, problem solved for now, I have removed pytube3 and installed pytube on my PC and it is working again.  So I guess pytube3 is broken.